# Azure storage blob client side encryption does not decrypt Java

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage

Azure storage blob, uploaded a blob using client-side encryption, using CEK and KEK. And now trying to download the decrypted file using the KEK on the client-side. But the file gets downloaded and does not decrypt. Shows only the encrypted file.

```
public class KeyVaultGettingStarted {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws StorageException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException,
            URISyntaxException, InvalidKeyException, IOException {
        Utility.printSampleStartInfo("KeyVaultGettingStarted");

        // Get the key ID from Utility if it exists.
        String keyID = Utility.keyVaultKeyID;

        // If no key ID was specified, we will create a new secret in Key Vault.
        // To create a new secret, this client needs full permission to Key
        // Vault secrets.
        // Once the secret is created, its ID can be added to App.config. Once
        // this is done,
        // this client only needs read access to secrets.
        if (keyID == null || keyID.isEmpty()) {
            keyID = KeyVaultUtility.createSecret("KVGettingStartedSecret");
        }

        // Retrieve storage account information from connection string
        // How to create a storage connection string -
        // https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-configure-connection-string/
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount
                .parse(Utility.storageConnectionString);

        CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = client
                .getContainerReference("blobencryptioncontainer"
                        + UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", ""));
        container.createIfNotExists();

        // Construct a resolver capable of looking up keys and secrets stored in
        // Key Vault.

        KeyVaultKeyResolver cloudResolver = new KeyVaultKeyResolver(
                KeyVaultUtility.GetKeyVaultClient());


        // To demonstrate how multiple different types of key can be used, we
        // also create a local key and resolver.
        // This key is temporary and won't be persisted.
        final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyGen.initialize(1024);
        final KeyPair wrapKey = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

        RsaKey rsaKey = new RsaKey("rsaKey1", wrapKey);
        LocalResolver resolver = new LocalResolver();
        resolver.add(rsaKey);

        // If there are multiple key sources like Azure Key Vault and local KMS,
        // set up an aggregate resolver as follows.
        // This helps users to define a plug-in model for all the different key
        // providers they support.
        AggregateKeyResolver aggregateResolver = new AggregateKeyResolver();
        aggregateResolver.Add(resolver);
        aggregateResolver.Add(cloudResolver);


        // Set up a caching resolver so the secrets can be cached on the client.
        // This is the recommended usage
        // pattern since the throttling targets for Storage and Key Vault
        // services are orders of magnitude
        // different.
        CachingKeyResolver cachingResolver = new CachingKeyResolver(1,
                aggregateResolver);

        // Create a key instance corresponding to the key ID. This will cache
        // the secret.
        IKey cloudKey = cachingResolver.resolveKeyAsync(keyID).get();

        System.out.println(cloudKey.toString());

        try {
            container.createIfNotExists();
            int size = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
            String a = "this is the encrypted message.";

            // The first blob will use the key stored in the Azure Key Vault.
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("blockblob1");

            BlobEncryptionPolicy uploadPolicy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(
                    cloudKey, null);

            // Set the encryption policy on the request options.
            BlobRequestOptions uploadOptions = new BlobRequestOptions();
            uploadOptions.setEncryptionPolicy(uploadPolicy);

            System.out.println("Uploading the 1st encrypted blob.");

            // Upload the encrypted contents to the blob.
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new 
            ByteArrayInputStream(a.getBytes());
            blob.upload(inputStream, size, null, uploadOptions, null);

            // Download the encrypted blob.
            BlobEncryptionPolicy downloadPolicy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(
                    null,cachingResolver);

            // Set the decryption policy on the request options.
            BlobRequestOptions downloadOptions = new BlobRequestOptions();
            downloadOptions.setEncryptionPolicy(downloadPolicy);
            System.out.println(downloadOptions.toString());

            System.out.println("Downloading the 1st encrypted blob.");

            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            blob.download(outputStream, null, downloadOptions, null);
            blob.downloadToFile("C:\\Users\\kashyap\\Downloads\\abc.txt");
}
```

Azure storage blob, uploaded a blob using client-side encryption, using CEK and KEK. And now trying to download the decrypted file using the KEK on the client-side. But the file gets downloaded and does not decrypt. Shows only the encrypted file.

Comment: Is that you use the same key to decrypt and encrypt the blob?

Comment: Have my solution solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two doc may give you some help:

[doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-client-side-encryption-java?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#blob-service-encryption)

[doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob._cloud_blob.downloadtofile?view=azure-java-legacy)

please tranform the download method to:

`blob.downloadToFile("C:\\Users\\kashyap\\Downloads\\abc.txt", null, uploadOptions, null);`

You can see that the picture that I uploaded to azure blob is broken:
[image]

But when I downloaded it with this method, It turned back to picture again:

[image]
[image]

It works on my side. If you have more question, please let me know.

Comment: @KashyapSoni glad to help.

Comment: i have same problem - Azure storage blob client side encryption does not decrypt DOTNET - i have used await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms, null, options, null);